# Create Australian date in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to create an Australian date table in our SQL Server 2008 database.

I understand the best way to do this is with T-SQL, can anyone provide a script to create the table, then the T-SQL script to populate?

Notes: although this doesn't have Australian holidays, I tried following the below resource, however was met with the error (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho)

> Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstLeapYearInPeriod".

Comment: There are many reference to `Calendar Table`, just search for it. Best is understand what you want and refer to samples from your search and implement only the portion that you want. Most of them might have include many more things that you might not need at all. On the error message, you must have missed out something in the `copy & paste` process

Comment: If you're copy-pasting code from that article (instead of using the .zip file) there are a lot of errors introduced by formatting: lines ending with `_` characters, comments broken across lines, etc.